# C++ wstring find compilation error

Tags: c++, find, wstring

I am trying to find the position of the tab character in a wstring.

However it does not work for me.

```
    int n = wline.find(L"\t");
```

n is -1 although I know for sure that there is a tab character in the wstring.

Does anybody see my error? I was thinking that maybe L"\t" might not be correct, but when I removed the L, it wouldn't compile anymore.

Edit: I am posting the entire code now, perhaps the problem is somewhere else:

```
void clsCharacterTranslations::LoadSerializedCharacters(string file)
{

FILE* inFile =  fopen(file.c_str(), "rb");

wchar_t signature[2];
fread(signature, sizeof(wchar_t), 1, inFile);

wstring wline;

while (GetLineW(inFile, wline))
{
    udtCharacterTranslation st;

    int b = 0;
    int n = wline.find(L"\t");
    wstring ws1 = wline.substr(0,n-b);

    b = n+1;
    n = wline.find(L"\t",b);
    wstring ws2 = wline.substr(b,n-b);

    st.Text = ws1;
    st.Translation = ws1;

    m_content.push_back(st);
}

fclose(inFile);

}

bool GetLineW(FILE *inFile, wstring &result)
{
wchar_t data[2]={0,0};

result = L"";
do{
    fread(data, sizeof(wchar_t), 1, inFile);

    if (data[0]>=L' ')
        result += data;

    if (data[0]==0x0A)
        break;
}while(!feof(inFile));

if (result.size()>0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

I am reading the 2 first characters at the beginning of the void because the text file is in Windows "Unicode" format.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the type of `wline`, and what does it contain? Can you provide a minimal compilable example showing the problem?

Comment: Are you **really** sure there is a tab in the string? Have you tried printing it out or looking at it in a debugger to make sure?

Comment: No, I am not sure. I guess something in my GetLineW garbages the line.

Comment: Perhaps somebody can tell me how a line from a Unicode text file should be properly read. I guess that might be really helpful.

Comment: @tmighty, that is a different question. I suggest you ask it separately.

Comment: If you are using C++, why not use C++ streams? If you use e.g. [`wifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) you can use that to read one line at a time very easily.

Comment: Also, if the file doesn't really contain wide characters, then you can't read it as if it were. You have then to read it as narrow characters (i.e. normal `char`) and then _widen_ it to wide characters.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I am really newbie to C++, and last time I tried something like that I did not get it to work and somewhen gave up.

Comment: http://ideone.com/PAghuw what compilation error? Please edit your question to reflect a real problem.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: " if the file doesn't really contain wide characters, then you can't read it as if it were" -- incorrect, files do not contain wide or narrow characters. They contain characters encoded with one of many existing encodings. Stream data type and file encoding are orthogonal, you can well read ASCII-encoded data with a `wstream`.

Comment: @n.m. I'm thinking more about "character size" than the actual encoding.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: there's no notion of character size in a file separate from the encoding. There are single-byte encodings (e.g. ASCII), constant-width multibyte encodings (e.g. UTF32LE) and variable-width multibyte encodings (e.g. UTF8) and any of them can be read with either regular or wide C++ streams.